# How can I skip intermediate table in SQLalchemy has_many through

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, has-many-through

I have 3 tables:

`users: id, name`, `user_cameras: id, user_id, camera_id, sort_order`, and `camera: id, name`

I want to fetch `user.cameras` so that it will return me `Camera` objects with `sort_order` field

From user point of view `user_camera` and `camera` is a one-to-one relation

Is it possible to do what I want or it is a too bad and complicated magic?

SQLAlchemy calls something like this an Association object: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html#association-pattern

It offers to do:

```
p = Parent()
a = Association(extra_data="some data")
a.child = Child()
p.children.append(a)
```

I want to do:

```
p = Parent()
p.children.append(Child())
```

or maybe even:

```
p = Parent()
c = Child()
c.extra_data = "some data"
p.children.append(c)
```

Perhaps last thing is not a good idea.
But I definitely want to do:

```
for child in p.children:
    print child.extra_data
    print child.name
```

and

```
p.children.remove(child)
```

Comment: Not sure I've understood... If you say that from user point of way everything is a one-to-one relation, user.cameras would give you one object only. Anyway, I'd say the only thing you need is a join.

Comment: I mean that it is technically possible to make something like:  user.cameras where each camera in cameras will have sort_order that is fetched from user_cameras table

Comment: Sure you can. That's just a join. Take a look to [this link](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html#querying-with-joins). In your case, it's ok if you just join `user_cameras` and `camera`. In the example in the link, it is as if  `camera` is `User` and `user_cameras` is `Address`. I'd use the 2nd syntax, something like, `session.query(camera).join(user_camera, camera.id = user_camera.camera_id)`. Hope it helps.